Проблемы с запуском vue проекта на ngrok и через порты vs code
Я очень люблю временно хостить проекты на ngrok'е или через vs code.
node.js на них работает без проблем, а с vue у меня проблемы.
В случае с ngrok'ом я пробую:
ngrok.exe http 8080

или
ngrok.exe tcp 8080

В любом случае когда перехожу по ссылке, которую он мне дал получаю:
Invalid Host header

В случае vs code я создаю порт:

Но когда захожу на него получаю ошибку:
Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.


Подскажите, пожалуйста, что с ним сделать чтобы он запустился нормально

Решение оказалось очень простым!
Пишете:
npm run build

Если Вы используете yarn, то:
yarn build

Дальше документация vue рекомендует установить serve:
npm install -g serve

или
yarn add serve

А затем в папке с vue проектом запустить:
serve -s dist

Проект запуститься на порту (у меня это был 3000, он напишет),
и используете этот порт как хотите.
Но ничего не будет динамически обновляться когда вы изменяете файлы!
